# C overwrite return address to a function cause kernel panic

Tags: c

I'm doing a bit reverse engineering practice and I got stuck at this problem. The general idea is that having a process P1 call a function, f1(). At the beginning of f1() I let it sleep so our evil process P2 can kick in. In P2, I overwrite the return address on f1()'s stack to our evil function, fevil(). But when f1() wakes up, it crashes before jump to fevil().

More detail:

1. I'm using a kind of OS without any memory protection. Every process can read/write the 
   whole memory range.
2. The whole thing runs on x86 architecture.
3. The way I do it is locate the return address on the call stack of f1(), let's say 0xffeecc, and do

   ```
   *((int*) 0xffeecc) = fevil;
   ```
4. I'm using gcc and all sort of standard C stuff.
5. The OS is single thread, and these two processes are the only two running, in additional to main process.

So the question is why the whole thing crashes, and if it's the correct way to jump to a function by the address of the function.

I can provide more details upon request. Thank you.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @dvnrrs thanks for raising this problem. The question is why the whole thing crashes, and if it's the correct way to jump to a function by address.

Comment: The type of your l-value is int, are you sure that sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void *)? Try using a pointer to a pointer instead of a pointer to int.

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't catch that. The general idea seems sound to me - it should work. Are you sure you have the correct address? Are there calling convention issues coming into play? What is the "crash" - jump to random code, CPU exception, etc.? Is the CPU in protected mode?

Comment: @Fernando Yep, sizeof(int*) == sizeof(void*) == 4 (byte) That's one of the parts I'm confused. How to use pointer casting in this case?

Comment: @fleetC0m what you should compare in your case is `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *)`. In the assignment you can write `*((void**) 0xffeecc = fevil` in that way the type of you l-value is a pointer.

Comment: @dvnrrs Correct address... hmmm, I think so. Calling convention... Don't think so, since I'm not passing arguments to fevil() and I don't care how to return from fevil(). The crash is general protection violation

Comment: How did you figure out the location of the return address on P1's stack?  I'm surprised you didn't get a warning in attempting to assign a function pointer to an `int`.  How is `fevil` declared?

Comment: If you get a 'general protection violation' then clearly your detail #1 is incorrect.

Comment: You should step through the assembly code of `f1()` after it wakes up in a debugger to see what's going on.  If you're working on this kind of hack, you should become comfortable with debugging at the assembly language level.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your compiler might implement some memory protection : like [canaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection) against buffer overflow/stack-smashing.

It inserts magic words before the return address and check its integrity before jumping at it.
You may have overwritten this marker.